# What to Save As when exporting Visio .vsd to OpenOffice or LibreOffice to minimize differences?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, microsoft-visio

I have a Microsoft Visio Pro. 2010 file (.vsd), and I want to work with it in LibreOffice (or OpenOffice, as a secondary option).

When I import the .vsd file to LibreOffice, there are many differences on the pages, mostly associated with font line size, paragraph settings inconsistency and layout.

Is there a preferable standard I can export the file (Save As) in Visio so that the differences are minimized when opening it in LibreOffice (or OpenOffice, which apparently cannot open the 2010 vsd)?

Comment: OpenOffice is dead, though?

Comment: What style of diagram is it? Flowchart, Floor plan, PERT chart, UML diagram or ... what?

Comment: Judicious use of text boxes with different paragraph settings to design a page layout design. Paragraph settings on boxes (line heights, margins, spacing) and positioning are not being retained.

Answer (score 1):

Libre Office can open .vsd files directly. However, Libre Office may not understand some of the niceties within the Visio file and may provide its own default settings for fonts and sizes etc. I certainly wouldn't try round-trip editing, i.e. don't edit with Libre Office, save it and then expect 100% compatibilty with opening it again in Visio.